# How to make row using input joption on java netbeans

Tags: java, loops

I have a some question about Looping to create especially 7 rows using JOptionPane.
This is my code and the result like this => 3 8 9 16 27 24 81

```
    int nilai=3;
    int penjulahan = 1;
    int n= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inputkan "));

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
         System.out.println(nilai);
         penjulahan =penjulahan*2 ;
         nilai = nilai+penjulahan  ;
}
```

if i running the code will result 3
5
9
17
33
65
129

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following code. You just need to verify the entered values for the number of rows.

```
public class MyTest
{
    JFrame f;
    MyTest()
    {
        f=new JFrame();
        int nilai=3;
        int penjulahan = 1;
        int n = -1;
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inputkan "));

        if( n > -1 )
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(nilai);
                System.out.print("\t");
                penjulahan = penjulahan * 2;
                nilai = nilai + penjulahan;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        new MyTest();
    }
}
```

Frame looks like

[image]

Output will be in the console

[image]